Strange work of showframe package
I am trying to write a simple class and set all necessary parameters (paper size, font size, margins, header, footer, etc.) by myself.  I do not want to load complex classes like article, report, book, etc. and then modify them reducing their functionality.
I started from setting paper size in mm (height=297mm x width=210mm) and corresponding text area size (height=257mm x width=175mm).  It looks easy.  I activated package "showframe", and frames indicated correct text box.  However, after deactivating package "showframe", the lower boundary of the text box wend down outside the page.  This is strange because paperheight(297mm) less textheight(257mm) is 4 centimiters, which is quite enough for header and footer.
Has anyone seen this problem?  Any advise is welcome.  Thanks!
The class code is:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ke_report_tech}[2024/06/12 Class for technical reports writing]

\pagestyle{empty}

% Set font (14pt) and baselines spacing (14pt x 1.5 = 21pt):
\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{14pt}{21pt}\selectfont}

% Set A4-paper size (portrait orientation):
\setlength\paperwidth       {210mm}
\setlength\paperheight      {297mm}

\setlength\textwidth        {175mm}
\setlength\textheight       {257mm}

The main.tex code is:
\documentclass{ke_report_tech}
%\documentclass{minimal}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}
This is a test of my first document class.

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Parameter          & Value                                           \\
Paper width        & \the\paperwidth   \\
Paper height       & \the\paperheight  \\
Text width         & \the\textwidth    \\
Text height        & \the\textheight   \\
Header height      & \the\headheight   \\
Header separator   & \the\headsep      \\
Top margin         & \the\topmargin    \\
Footer skip        & \the\footskip     \\
Footnote separator & \the\footnotesep  \\
Text size          & %\the\normalfont
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[4-8]

\blindtext[1-10]

\lipsum[9-15]
\end{document}


Welcome! You need to do rather more than you do here to have a functional class. But the particular problem is due to your only setting \textheight and \paperheight. So everything else is default, including margins, header etc. You've done nothing to set any of that.

Note that a top margin of 0pt will start the text block 25.4mm from the top of the paper. Likewise for left margin. So if you want 20mm, you need to set it to -5.4mm.

the showframe package loads the graphics package and that sets the pdf mediabox. You can (for pdftex, other engines have other commands) do this manually with \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth \pdfpageheight=\paperheight.
